# How to make select option as a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Laravel for creating shopping cart 
so I want to make something for select number of product by customer and when customer click e.g on number 2 page will be refresh and new price is going to show
my problem is that I don't know how can I make a select box as a button that whenever each user click on each number something happen

here is my html

```
  <div class="selectric-hide-select">
          <select class="c-ui-select js-ui-select" id="expressShipping-count-0" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1">
           <option value="1">۱</option>
                       <option value="2">۲</option>
                       <option value="3">۳</option>
                       <option value="4" selected="">۴</option>
                       <option value="5">۵</option>
           </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: you can refresh prize on change event of select box

Comment: You can use jquery `onchange()` method

Comment: Just use `$('#expressShipping-count-0').on('change', function() { alert($(this).val()); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have button inside select box rather you can make use of change event of select box and refresh the prize.

see below code

```js
$(function(){
   $('#expressShipping-count-0').on('change', function(){
       var value = $(this).val();
       console.log(value);
       // recalculate prize and show
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectric-hide-select">
          <select class="c-ui-select js-ui-select" id="expressShipping-count-0" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1">
           <option value="1">۱</option>
                       <option value="2">۲</option>
                       <option value="3">۳</option>
                       <option value="4" selected="">۴</option>
                       <option value="5">۵</option>
           </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: that's it tnq so much for helping

Comment: happy to help you :)